# puppeteer page.click() gets stuck after uploading a file

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload, puppeteer

I'm uploading a file and then trying to click continue but it doesn't click on continue. Check the attached code snippet

```
const elementHandle = await page.$("input[type=file]");
  await elementHandle.uploadFile(
    "E:/Learning/JavaScript/Projects/Automation/Downer/upload.docx"
  );

  await page.waitFor(300);
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    await page.click("#saveContinue"),
  ]);
  await page.screenshot({ path: "example.png" });
```

If I'm commenting upload file code then it does click on the continue so it's working without upload file but not working with upload file code. I've also tried it outside of the Promise.all and It kinda gets stuck neither it throws an error nor clicks on the continue.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on [this](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/857#issuecomment-386222936) it appears that puppeteer expects relative path (official docs are not clear in this matter, though). Have you tried specifying path relatively to cwd?

So, assuming your script is in `E:/Learning/JavaScript/Projects/Automation/Downer`:

```
const filePath = path.relative(process.cwd(), __dirname + '/upload.docx');
const input = await page.$('input[type=file]');
await input.uploadFile(filePath);
```

And, by the way - *without upload code it works* - but without await for `input` and the upload itself, or only without the uploadFile?

Comment: Hi. Same issue with your code. It doesn't click on the continue button after uploading the file but when I'm commenting your entire code then it does click on continue. Thanks